# is there any way to merging values inside array of objects with same key value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, object

this is the json i have and im trying to merge the objects with respect to toolName

```
[
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Login",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " Find The Job That Fits Your Life",
              "toolValueId": "097a5264-1370-fc61-299d-648014d4d5a5",
              "toolValueName": "Locate login button (optional)"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Search Website",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Continue with Facebook orContinue account with EmailPasswordPassword must be at least 8 characters, no spaces Continue with Email",
              "toolValueId": "d267005a-61cc-041b-cc35-406f14e81fec",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Explore Glassdoor",
              "toolValueId": "e1211bc9-72d9-6f29-5a12-ebb5df7cae90",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Login",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Find the Right Job",
              "toolValueId": "7aab0479-39bf-9690-3948-9b52af4d1e51",
              "toolValueName": "Locate User Name edit box"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Search Website",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Millions of jobs. Search by what matters to you and find the one thats right for you.",
              "toolValueId": "c68ed1b8-c2bf-9ea7-62c0-2e80e7911a53",
              "toolValueName": "newAttributehvjh"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " or",
              "toolValueId": "fd29e018-b8b6-4015-a3ce-121e2d8048af",
              "toolValueName": "newAttributehvjh"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Login",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " Find The Job That Fits Your Life By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Continue with Facebook orContinue account with EmailPasswordPassword must be at least 8 characters, no spaces Continue with Email Are You Hiring? Post Jobs",
              "toolValueId": "cd551cd9-a511-b6ce-611a-d0fed61db448",
              "toolValueName": "Enter User Name"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Search Website",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Glassdoor",
              "toolValueId": "72ce7dfb-9a05-41ce-c882-a489a074c5c9",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " Are You Hiring? Post Jobs",
              "toolValueId": "9bcc2da4-e244-74ab-c36b-eaf9117bb46f",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

the desired output is

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "toolName": "Login",
      "data": [
        {
          "scrapValue": " Find The Job That Fits Your Life",
          "toolValueId": "097a5264-1370-fc61-299d-648014d4d5a5",
          "toolValueName": "Locate login button (optional)"
        },
        {
          "scrapValue": "Find the Right Job",
          "toolValueId": "7aab0479-39bf-9690-3948-9b52af4d1e51",
          "toolValueName": "Locate User Name edit box"
        },
        {
          "scrapValue": " Find The Job That Fits Your Life By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Continue with Facebook orContinue account with EmailPasswordPassword must be at least 8 characters, no spaces Continue with Email Are You Hiring? Post Jobs",
          "toolValueId": "cd551cd9-a511-b6ce-611a-d0fed61db448",
          "toolValueName": "Enter User Name"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "toolName": "Search Website",
      "data": [
        {
          "scrapValue": " By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Continue with Facebook orContinue account with EmailPasswordPassword must be at least 8 characters, no spaces Continue with Email",
          "toolValueId": "d267005a-61cc-041b-cc35-406f14e81fec",
          "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
        },
        {
          "scrapValue": "Millions of jobs. Search by what matters to you and find the one thats right for you.",
          "toolValueId": "c68ed1b8-c2bf-9ea7-62c0-2e80e7911a53",
          "toolValueName": "newAttributehvjh"
        },
        {
          "scrapValue": "Glassdoor",
          "toolValueId": "72ce7dfb-9a05-41ce-c882-a489a074c5c9",
          "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
      "data": [
        {
          "scrapValue": "Explore Glassdoor",
          "toolValueId": "e1211bc9-72d9-6f29-5a12-ebb5df7cae90",
          "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
        },
        {
          "scrapValue": " or",
          "toolValueId": "fd29e018-b8b6-4015-a3ce-121e2d8048af",
          "toolValueName": "newAttributehvjh"
        },
        {
          "scrapValue": " Are You Hiring? Post Jobs",
          "toolValueId": "9bcc2da4-e244-74ab-c36b-eaf9117bb46f",
          "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Iam trying to merge the value of the array of objects of data array with respect to the toolName of the above pair of objects and
I have tried the following way but didnt worked out

```
var result = [...this.scrapingProcedure.reduce((m, o) => {
        var key = ['toolName'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        if (m.has(key)) {
            m.get(key).data.push(...o.data);
        } else {
            m.set(key, Object.assign({}, o, { data: o.data }));
        }
        return m;
    }, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

and it is showing an error ERROR TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator on this line m.get(key).data.push(...o.data);

anyhelp would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you expand on what *"didnt worked out"* means - compare the actual outputs with what you expected.

Comment: there is actually no output showing this error ERROR TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

Comment: That error suggests you're spreading something that isn't an array, so what *is* `o.data`? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple implementation using reduce

```js
const data = [
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Login",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " Find The Job That Fits Your Life",
              "toolValueId": "097a5264-1370-fc61-299d-648014d4d5a5",
              "toolValueName": "Locate login button (optional)"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Search Website",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Continue with Facebook orContinue account with EmailPasswordPassword must be at least 8 characters, no spaces Continue with Email",
              "toolValueId": "d267005a-61cc-041b-cc35-406f14e81fec",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Explore Glassdoor",
              "toolValueId": "e1211bc9-72d9-6f29-5a12-ebb5df7cae90",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Login",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Find the Right Job",
              "toolValueId": "7aab0479-39bf-9690-3948-9b52af4d1e51",
              "toolValueName": "Locate User Name edit box"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Search Website",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Millions of jobs. Search by what matters to you and find the one thats right for you.",
              "toolValueId": "c68ed1b8-c2bf-9ea7-62c0-2e80e7911a53",
              "toolValueName": "newAttributehvjh"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " or",
              "toolValueId": "fd29e018-b8b6-4015-a3ce-121e2d8048af",
              "toolValueName": "newAttributehvjh"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Login",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " Find The Job That Fits Your Life By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Continue with Facebook orContinue account with EmailPasswordPassword must be at least 8 characters, no spaces Continue with Email Are You Hiring? Post Jobs",
              "toolValueId": "cd551cd9-a511-b6ce-611a-d0fed61db448",
              "toolValueName": "Enter User Name"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Search Website",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": "Glassdoor",
              "toolValueId": "72ce7dfb-9a05-41ce-c882-a489a074c5c9",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "toolName": "Capture Attribute",
          "data": [
            {
              "scrapValue": " Are You Hiring? Post Jobs",
              "toolValueId": "9bcc2da4-e244-74ab-c36b-eaf9117bb46f",
              "toolValueName": "newAttribute"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    
 const res = data.reduce((all, next) => {
    const current = all.find(v => v.data.toolName === next.data.toolName)
    if (current) {
      current.data.data = current.data.data.concat(next.data.data)
    } else {
      all.push(next)
    }
    return all
 }, [])
 
 console.log(res)
```